# What is the best way to setup JBoss for development and testing in the same machine

Tags: xml, jboss

I would like to know the best way to set up a development environment and a test environment in the same machine.

Currently i have two batch files that replaces the **standalone-full-ha.xml** with either **standalone-full-ha-local.xml** or **standalone-full-ha-test.xml**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the application design.

standalone.xml : This is the default configuration file for a standalone server. It contains all information about the standalone server, including subsystems, networking, deployments, socket bindings, and other configurable details

This configuration for a standalone server. It includes support for every possible subsystem except for those required for high availability

standalone-ha.xml: This configuration file enables the mod_cluster and JGroups subsystems for a standalone server, so that it can participate in a high-availability or load-balancing cluster. This file is not necessary for a managed domain.

This configuration file enables all of the default subsystems and adds the mod_cluster and JGroups subsystems for a standalone server, so that it can participate in a high-availability or load-balancing cluster. This file is not applicable for a managed domain

standalone-full.xml: This configuration for a standalone server. It includes support for every possible subsystem except for those required for high availability.

standalone-full-ha.xml: This configuration for a standalone server. It includes support for every possible subsystem, including those required for high availability.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this depending on whether you want both development and test to be running at the same time or whether you will only be running either one at one time.

**Scenario 1: You will be running only either development and test at one time** For this scenario, instead of replacing the standalone-ha xml file, you can keep both the files in the standalone/configuration directory and choose which file should be used by JBoss using the JVM parameter `-Djboss.server.default.config`.

To accomplish this, you can create 2 copies of the standalone.conf.bat (standalone.conf if using linux) file which is located in the bin folder. You can name them standalone-local.conf.bat and standalone-test.conf.bat.

In each file, you can use the JAVA_OPTS to specify which standalone xml file to use.

So, in `standalone-local.conf.bat` you would change the set JAVA_OPTS line to

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha-local.xml"
```

and in `standalone-test.conf.bat` you would change the set JAVA_OPTS line to

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha-test.xml"
```

If you have any other JVM parameters then you can add them to the above line.

Now create two copies of `standalone.bat` file (standalone.sh if using linux).

In the first copy named `standalone-local.bat` change the name of configuration file from `standalone.conf.bat to standalone-local.conf.bat. (located at line 92)`

In the second copy named `standalone-test.bat` change the name of the configuration file from `standalone.conf to standalone-test.conf.bat. (located at line 92)`.

Now your JBoss server is ready to run both dev and test (only one of them at one time though). If you start the Jboss server using `standalone-local.bat` then it will load your dev configuration. If you start the JBoss server using `standalone-test.bat` then it will load you test configuration.

**Scenario 2: You will be running both development and test at the same time**

For this scenario make sure that you have enough RAM to allocate to heaps of both JVMs.
Copy the complete jboss server folder to a new location. You will end up with 2 separate JBoss directories. (For example, `C:\jboss-dev\` and `C:\jboss-test\`).
Copy your dev standalone xml file to the `C:\jboss-dev\standalone\configuration`.
Copy your test standalone xml file to the `C:\jboss-test\standalone\configuration`.

In the `standalone.conf.bat` file (`standalone.conf` if using linux) of the dev jboss server which is located in the bin folder, add the following JVM parameter to the JAVA_OPTS

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100"
```

You can add any other JVM parameter that you need for your application to JAVA_OPTS. Adding `-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100` JVM parameter will offset all ports used by JBoss by 100. So, if the default port for HTTP is 8080 earlier, then after adding the above parameter, the dev JBoss server will use 8180 for HTTP. This will ensure that the ports used by this JBoss are not in conflict with any other JBoss server running on the same machine.

No change is needed for the test environment as it can use the default JBoss ports.

Now you can start both the dev and test JBoss server at the same time without any port conflicts and run both in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I figured it will be best to manually switch the environments by manually specify the which configs that points to different environment than to have a script that does this.  e.g standalone-full-ha-dev.xml or standalone-full-ha-uat.xml in the server runtime environment configs